# Using Laravel Facades with UserFrosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, userfrosting

Have recently starting using UserFrosting to as part of a project and I'm having some problems using Facades within UserFrosting and would appreciate some help if possible.

I am attempting to use the `File` facade from within a UserFrosting controller to create a folder on the local filesystem using the following code

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
......
$directoryCreated = File::makeDirectory($directoryPath);`

However at runtime i get the following error

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function makeDirectory() on null in /var/www/test-app/userfrosting/vendor/illuminate/support/Facades/Facade.php on line 210`

It seems that the UserFrosting app does not recognise the File facade (or any other facacde - i also tried Storage) and it has not been registered with the app.

Is it possible to use the facade classes with UserFrosting?

If so do I have to register them somewhere within the UserFrosting app config?

Any direction pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Facade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades):

> Laravel "facades" serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the service container...

So, it looks like Laravel's facades depend on Laravel's service container.  You can read more about how Laravel sets up the default facades here: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/#how-laravel-aliases-the-facades

Unfortunately, UserFrosting does not use Laravel's service container.  Rather, it uses [Slim](http://docs.slimframework.com/), which has its own service container.  In Slim v2 (which UF 0.3.1 uses), the Slim application *itself* is the service container.

You can define services for UF in [initialize.php](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/initialize.php).  So, you might try something like:

`$app->filesystem = new \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem();`

Then later, you can use the filesystem service like:

`$app->filesystem->makeDirectory($directoryPath);`

Comment: Thanks @alexw for this direction. I had imported and instantiated the filesystem object directly within the controller to use the makeDirectory method but your suggestion would be more elegant especially for reuse elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Slim's container to allow the Facade to resolve its accessor (it will use array access on the container to resolve it). You would have to make sure that the binding the facade uses exists. You can take a look at the Service Provider that corresponds to the service you want to use to know how its setting up the binding.

The `File` facade is accessing the binding 'files' (`Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`).

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::setFacadeApplication($container);

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::makeDirectory(...);
```

Its worth a shot, but its mostly the binding that is being resolved that is important.

Comment: Thanks @lagbox will investigate this option further. Ended up directly instantiating the filesystem object directly in order to create the directory, but eventually wished to be able to swap between local and cloud storage hence the desire to use Facades (File or Storage). This may move me a step closer.